# Getting this error on integrating Zoom SDk in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, sdk

I am not able to run build, I tried running flutter clean, flutter pub get, flutter pub run flutter_zoom_sdk:unzip_zoom_sdk

and after flutter run I am getting this error in my console

Currently using this version flutter_zoom_sdk: ^1.1.0+4

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform commonlib-.aar (:commonlib:) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=integration}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/adityaanand/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fefa4c810a121b04cd010685377f672e/jetified-commonlib.
         > /Users/adityaanand/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fefa4c810a121b04cd010685377f672e/jetified-commonlib/AndroidManifest.xml
   > Failed to transform mobilertc-.aar (:mobilertc:) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=integration}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/adityaanand/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fefa4c810a121b04cd010685377f672e/jetified-commonlib.
         > /Users/adityaanand/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fefa4c810a121b04cd010685377f672e/jetified-commonlib/AndroidManifest.xml

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 0):

After running pub get, you must run the following script to get Zoom SDK for the first time:

```
 flutter pub run flutter_zoom_sdk:unzip_zoom_sdk
```